# Yii view open CJuiDialog if PHP variable is true

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, yii

In the view part, I want to check if the $check value == true then open the CJuiDialog

```
<?php
if($check==true)
{
    js:function(){$('#dialogDisplay').dialog('open');}
}
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(// the dialog
    'id' => 'dialogDisplay',
    'options' => array(
        'title' => 'Display Setting',
        'autoOpen' => false,
        'modal' => true,
        'width' => 300,
        'height' => 200,
        'buttons' => array(
            array('text' => 'Submit', 'click' => 'js:function(){ document.myform.submit();}'),
            array('text' => 'Cancel', 'click' => 'js:function(){$(this).dialog("close");}')),
    ),
));
?>
<div class="divForForm">
    <form name="myform" action="/dataset/resetPageSize" method="post">  
        Items per page:
        <select name="filePageSize" class="selectPageSize">
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="10" selected>10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
            <option value="200">200</option>                 
        </select>
        <br>
        Size: <input type="checkbox" name="size" checked />
        <input type="hidden" name="url" value="<? echo Yii::app()->request->requestUri; ?>" />

    </form>

</div>    

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

but it doesn't work, i just start learn javascript , i don't know how to run it when $check==true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print out the script tag to the client:

```
<?php
// If PHP variable $check is true
if($check == true) {
    // Print out jQuery ready function to the client side, 
    //   which will run when the page loads
    echo "<script>$(function(){ $('#dialogDisplay').dialog('open'); })</script>";
}
```